# async/await return value and odering

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, es6-promise, async.js

If i have the below async function

```
async fn(){   
    await fn1() // build an updated index from the database

    let res2 = await fn2() // query the database index
        res2 = await fn3(res2) // do something with the index, then update the database

    await fn1() // build an updated index from the database again, but we don't need the new index
    return res2
}
```

In the above setup

- I want the database search to be fast, so I build and index to search it.
- After I build the index, I query the database (the freshly built index)
- Then fetch some data using that index, and depending on the result, I add some rows to the database.
- After that, I need the result of the query above, and I might just end the code execution there and return the result, but I need to leave the database index up-to-date, so I rebuild the index again, but this time, I don't really need the results.

How would I structure the above async function to be as optimised as possible and reduce the overall execution time.

I googled some examples out there which gave the following code:

[freecodecamp](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/avoiding-the-async-await-hell-c77a0fb71c4c)

```
  const pizzaPromise = selectPizza()
  const drinkPromise = selectDrink()
  await pizzaPromise
  await drinkPromise
```

I cant tell if the above code makes any difference? 
Isn't it just `a-signing` the `async function` to a `constant value`, then `await-ing` that value?

Comment: you can use Promise.all when you dont need to wait for one function to finish before running another

Comment: if you dont care about a promise result, simply remove the `await`. The event loop will continue and you will get your result without waiting for the promise resolution.

Comment: @ChrisLi In the above code, I don't really need the return values, but some functionality might break. I might get some stale data to use in `fn3` if I run `fn1` and `fn2` in parallel